# Getting numerical value for day of the month

Tags: macros, date

When I use `\today` it gives me

> July 11, 2022

I would like to get the numerical value of the day of the month instead. Kind of like this:

```
\todaynum
```

> 11

How could I make a command that would return the numerical value of the day of the month?

I can't add any packages to document... which I realize makes this significantly harder.

Comment: `\day`..........

Comment: `\newcommand{\daynumber}{\the\day}`